# What does "The update information is outdated...." mean and how can I solve it?

Tags: updates

I am new on linux platform. I have given these codes while installing adobe reader

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

Unfortunately, adobe reader didnt get installed.(I tried many times,but to no success.)
Then,

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
```

but in the end of the update phenomenon , there is some error message, and hopefully ,
`Failed to download..` something like that.
after that I tried some regular software updates , but in the end , I am getting a warning sign in my taskbar, indicating the below,

```
The update information is outdated.
This may be caused by network problems or may be caused 
by a repository that is no longer available.
Please update manually by clicking this icon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

```
wget -O ~/adobe.deb ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxml2:i386 libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libatk-adaptor:i386
sudo dpkg -i ~/adobe.deb
```

---

You mistakenly added the software source for precise (Ubuntu 12.04), but you are using Ubuntu 14.10 utopic. The correct commands to install Adobe Acrobat Reader in Ubuntu 14.10 are as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner" # remove precise repo
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ utopic partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

Since you are a new Linux user I will add some advice. You probably don't need to install Adobe Reader, and you would be better off trying the built-in Document Viewer application, which works perfectly well as a PDF reader in Ubuntu, before you install a bloatware application like Adobe Reader.

Comment: Sir, I am not getting that warning sign anymore.
Does that mean , my software source has changed to that of Ubuntu 14.10. If not, how can I change it??
Please help.

Comment: You are not getting the warning message anymore because you have already removed the wrong software source with the command: `sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"` (the -r option stands for remove). Your software sources are OK for 14.10 if your file at `/etc/apt/sources.list` (which is a text file) doesn't have any more lines that have `precise` in the line, excluding lines that start with the # character which are comments. Comments are not used as software sources.

Comment: both PPA now seem obsolete - this guide can help you install adobe reader in linux https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux